# Testing jQuery/JS output on Chrome developer tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a method that creates 2 arrays with data. I want to be able to include these arrays into JSON. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
        var configs = [];
        var testPages = [];
        $(".test input:checked").each(function() {
            testPages.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });
        $(".config input:checked").each(function() {
            configs.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });
        //console.log(configs);
        //console.log(testPages);

        var testJson = new Object();
        testJson.testpages = testPages;
        testJson.configurations = configs;
        var runTestJson = JSON.stringify(testJson);
        return runTestJson;
    });
});
```

I want to be able to test this against my page but I am new to jQuery, Javascript and also using Chrome developer tools. I'm not sure how to test this in the Chrome console.

The commented portion (`console.log()s`) were displayed but when I type `configs` or `testPages` to try to view the array, I would get the error that they were undefined. How do I test to see if I am getting the correct output for my code on Chrome developer tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can debug your JavaScript without populating global space as follows (*Instruction based on `chrome`, but similar in major browsers*):

- Open developer console <kbd>F12</kbd>
- go to `Sources` tab
- Open your script file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> and type the filename)
- Put a breakpoint by clicking on the line number you wish to debug
- Refresh your page an execution will be stopped at that line

. You can further use the available controls in the debug toolbar:
<sub>[image]</sub>

to proceed the execution as you wish, each controls have self-descriptive tooltips. You can see the values in variables by hovering over them or manually selecting them.

Comment: When you mean populating global space, do you mean putting variables in the global scope? I am also curious as to if all the the JS/jQ code is required to be within `$(document).ready(function() {})`. I read somewhere that code should be within that function so that the code is loaded before the rest of the page.

Comment: @Liondancer Globalspace meaning the `window` object. If you simply create a variable outside a function or omit the `var` keyword, the variable will be a property of the window object which you can access like `window.variablename`.

Comment: ... `.ready()` method is prefered to make sure that the `DOM` is created before your script runs, ensuring all the events handlers, styles etc are properly attached... If part of your script doesn't interfere with `DOM` then it doesn't necessarily have to be in `ready()`

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to make those two variables global. Just beware that unnecessarily polluting the global scope is not recommended. But if it's just for testing, then i suppose it's OK.

```
// global scope
var configs = [];
var testPages = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".test input:checked").each(function() {
            testPages.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });
        $(".config input:checked").each(function() {
            configs.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });
        //console.log(configs);
        //console.log(testPages);

        var testJson = new Object();
        testJson.testpages = testPages;
        testJson.configurations = configs;
        var runTestJson = JSON.stringify(testJson);
        return runTestJson;
    });
});
```